# Can't read/write via `dd`: got /dev/disk2: Permission denied (to Physical device)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, permission, iterm

I can't do anything via `dd` with my Physical devices agreed.
I can only work with partitions like `disk2s1`, but can not read from whole disk like  `disk2`.
Can't find where is the root of problem.

Steps:

1. Check disks: `diskutil list`
2. Unmount: `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2`

Then

```
$ sudo dd bs=4m if=/dev/disk2 of=~/Desktop/PiOS_full_root.img
dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied
```

What causes this problem? why `dd` sends this error from `sudo`

---

there are similar topics around. What've tried, but doesn't works:

- [“dd: /dev/disk4: Permission denied” error when making LiveUSB on Mac OS X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215262/dd-dev-disk4-permission-denied-error-when-making-liveusb-on-mac-os-x)

and many others. nothing is helps.

- I check system preferences and gave full disk access to iTerm2 (doesn't help)
- unmount via `diskutil unmountDisk` and `diskutil unmount`
- Change USB ports (many people said because of the physical lock of sd card.
- change `disk` / `rdisk` naming - result the same
- Lock\unlock state doesn't affect it (it's microUSB, put without adapter into the microsd slot)

#### Any suggestions, what to check, and how to fix it?

#### Here is the log:

[image: log]

```
~ ❯ diskutil list                                                                                                                                                                                 
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     437.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 80.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.2 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.9 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    268.4 MB   disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         15.7 GB    disk2s2


 ~ ❯ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2                                                                                                                                                               
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful

 ~ ❯ sudo dd bs=1m if=/dev/rdisk2 of=~/Pi_Backup.img
dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied

 ~ ❯ ls -lhdO /dev/disk2                                                                                                                                                                           
brw-r-----  1 root  operator  -   1,   9 Jul 11 17:39 /dev/disk2
```

---

Update: another interesting thing: I chack disk in disk utility -> Get info -it's not writable!

But if I mount boot partition `disk2s1` - I can write there!

Comment: You want to read the disk, missing wrote permissions shouldn’t be an issue

Comment: agreed. now I can't even read it. only work with partitions like `disk2s1`, not whole disk `disk2`

Comment: Did you reboot already?

Comment: sure reboot and change all the ports for microsd

Comment: make sure that disk2 is unmounted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize that exactly the same setup is working on other MacBooks and even with another admin user on this laptop. So no matter, what kind o issue it is: I think it's something related to my personal setup and setting, not to the system in general. So I will close this question for now.

**If someone get the same problem:** try to do the same steps as I  described above or in the end: change the machine or user on your one if there is a chance to do this.

1. make sure that `diskX` is unmounted via `diskutil unmountDisk` and `diskutil unmount`
2. Change USB ports
3. if it's SD card: blow with air into the slot (many people said because of the physical lock sensor of sd card.
4. make sure, that you work via `sudo`. (just in case, you can check it via `which sudo` command)

Comment: This is the second time the Internet has provided me the same solution: blowing into the SD slot like we used to do with video game cartridges. To anybody finding the suggestion incredulous: How much more time would you like to lose because the solution is too silly?

Comment: Silly, I know, but it just worked for me! Had a SD card that was showing up as read-only. I removed the card, blew on the card contacts, blew into the SD card slot on the Mac (this is an older Mac with a built-in SD card slot, that hadn't been used in a while). It worked! Tried the SD card again, and it is now letting me write to it.

Comment: I just had a similar argument with the SD card slot in an older MBP. I did have to clear the dust out of the slot, but the thing that fixed the "Permission denied" was taking out the SD card adapter (the "fake" SD card that lets me use a microSD card in the slot), and sliding the tiny "lock" switch on it back and forth a few times, then setting back to unlocked - put it in again, and suddenly I could write to the (microSD) card.

Comment: @Krellan same her - I just had to move the write protection switch in the microSD adaptor

Comment: While this answer is essentially "Did you try turning it off and then back on" equivalent advice, it is correct.  Graphically un-mounting or using "mount" isn't good enough.  Even though you won't see the device in /dev, re-mount it, then remove it with diskutil.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: OP steps are correct. If you follow all the earlier caveats, the problem is (likely) due to the hardware you are using.

I had the same "permission denied" problem and tried all the earlier suggestions with no improvement. I was using the built-in MicroCard port of a UGreen brand thunderbolt port expander (MBP2019-Intel, plus an older Intel-based machine plugging it into a USB port using a converter).  Also tried several Linux VMs, in Parallels and VirtualBox, on the same machines. The thunderbolt port expander does correctly read/write ordinary files on MicroSD cards.

Then I tried plugging an **older UGreen USB-based card reader into the UGreen thunderbolt gizmo**.  **That worked** on the MBP; it's blazingly slow.

I've previously been disappointed with other UGreen devices, but all the low-end options look like they use the same boards with different casings for branding.  They all get crappy ratings.  (Hint: don't use the charging port if you can avoid it.) I'm not convinced the more expensive ones would be any better, but maybe I'm too pessimistic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/334321)